# KafkaRDD scala minimal example

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to get a running example using KafkaRDD:

```
val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092")
val offsetRanges = Array(
    OffsetRange("topic", 0, 0, 2)
)
val rdd = KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](sc, kafkaParams, offsetRanges)
rdd.map(x => println(x)).collect()

res: Array[Unit] = Array((), ())
```

I have been careful in creating "topic" with a single partition and writing 2 messages, hello, world.

I can get what looks like a correct RDD, but how can I access its content? Am I missing something?

Thanks, E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line, I believe:

```
rdd.map(x => println(x)).collect()
```

The way an RDD works, `rdd.map` runs on the executor. When you `println` it's printing it to `stdout` for the executor. To print it to `stdout` in the driver application, try this instead:

```
rdd.collect().map(x => println(x))
```